# Expectation of a product of $n$ dependent random variables when $n\to\infty$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable, expected-value, convergence

Let $X_1 \sim U[0,1]$ and $X_i \sim U[X_{i - 1}, 1]$, $i = 2, 3,...$. What is the expectation of $X_1 X_2 \cdots X_n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: A pedantic remark: is $X_i \sim U[X_{i - 1}, 1]$ intended to mean $X_i \mid X_1,\ldots,X_{i-1} \sim U[X_{i-1},1]$?  Alternatively it could mean  conditioning only on $X_{i-1}$, that is, $X_i \mid X_{i-1}  \sim U[X_{i-1},1]$. But as the latter does not completely specify the joint distribution of the $X_i$s, it is not immediately clear  whether the expectation is uniquely determined.

Comment: I think theoretically it should be conditioned on all the previous $X_i$ up till $X_{i - 1}$. However, given $X_{i - 1}$ we can get the distribution for $X_i$. So I'm not quite sure about this.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala As stated it doesn't matter if you condition on the variables before $X_{i-1}$ because they wouldn't change the fact that $X_i$ is uniform$[X_{i-1}, 1]$.  The distribution of $(X_1, \ldots , X_n)$ seems perfectly well-defined to me.

Comment: @dsaxton If we only assume $X_1\sim U(0,1)$ and $X_i\mid X_{i-1} \sim U(X_{i-1},1), i=2,3,...$, it remains possible that $X_1$ and $X_3$ are not conditionally independent conditional on $X_2$.  Thus the distribution of $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is not well-defined.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala If I tell you that $X_2=t$, what is the distribution of $X_3$?  If you can answer the question without even thinking about $X_1$, how can $X_1$ and $X_3$ be dependent given $X_2$?  Also notice how other posters have had no trouble simulating this sequence.

Comment: Other posters have no trouble as they made the (reasonable) assumption that the process is intended to be Markovian.

Comment: @dsaxton Is your claim just that the notation in the question tacitly implies the Markovianity assumption (which I could agree with, and which is why I admitted my remark to be pedantic)? Or do you dispute that specifying the distribution of $X_1$ and the conditionals $X_2\mid X_1$ and $X_3 \mid X_2$ does not uniquely specify the joint distribution?

Comment: In the latter case, this should perhaps be resolved in a separate question, as it is somewhat unrelated to this question (which most likely was intended to be about the Markovian process, and the answers are all assuming that anyway).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The answer is indeed $1/e$,** as guessed in the earlier replies based on simulations and finite approximations.

The solution is easily arrived at by introducing a sequence of functions $f_n: [0,1]\to[0,1]$. Although we could proceed to that step immediately, it might appear rather mysterious.  The first part of this solution explains how one might cook up these $f_n(t)$.  The second part shows how they are exploited to find a functional equation satisfied by the limiting function $f(t) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(t)$.  The third part displays the (routine) calculations needed to solve this functional equation.

---

### 1. Motivation

We can arrive at this by applying some standard mathematical problem-solving techniques.  In this case, where some kind of operation is repeated *ad infinitum,* the limit will exist as a *fixed point* of that operation.  The key, then, is to identify the operation.

The difficulty is that the move from $E[X_1X_2\cdots X_{n-1}]$ to $E[X_1X_2\cdots X_{n-1}X_n]$ looks complicated.  It is simpler to view this step as arising from adjoining $X_1$ to the variables $(X_2, \ldots, X_n)$ rather than adjoining $X_n$ to the variables $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{n-1})$. If we were to consider $(X_2, \ldots, X_n)$ as being constructed as described in the question--with $X_2$ uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, $X_3$ conditionally uniformly distributed on $[X_2, 1]$, and so on--then introducing $X_1$ will cause every one of the subsequent $X_i$ to *shrink by a factor of $1-X_1$ towards the upper limit $1$*. This reasoning leads naturally to the following construction.

As a preliminary matter, since it's a little simpler to shrink numbers towards $0$ than towards $1$, let $Y_i = 1-X_i$.  Thus, $Y_1$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$ and $Y_{i+1}$ is uniformly distributed in $[0, Y_i]$ conditional on $(Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_i)$ for all $i=1, 2, 3, \ldots.$  We are interested in two things:

1. The limiting value of $E[X_1X_2\cdots X_n]=E[(1-Y_1)(1-Y_2)\cdots(1-Y_n)]$.
2. How these values behave when shrinking all the $Y_i$ uniformly towards $0$: that is, by scaling them all by some common factor $t$, $0 \le t \le 1$.

To this end, define

$$f_n(t) = E[(1-tY_1)(1-tY_2)\cdots(1-tY_n)].$$

Clearly each $f_n$ is defined and continuous (infinitely differentiable, actually) for all real $t$.  We will focus on their behavior for $t\in[0,1]$.

---

### 2. The Key Step

The following are obvious:

1. Each $f_n(t)$ is a monotonically decreasing function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$.
2. $f_n(t) \gt f_{n+1}(t)$ for all $n$.
3. $f_n(0) = 1$ for all $n$.
4. $E(X_1X_2\cdots X_n) = f_n(1).$

These imply that $f(t) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(t)$ exists for all $t\in[0,1]$ and $f(0)=1$.

Observe that, conditional on $Y_1$, the variable $Y_2/Y_1$ is uniform in $[0,1]$ and variables $Y_{i+1}/Y_1$ (conditional on all preceding variables) are uniform in $[0, Y_i/Y_1]$: that is, **$(Y_2/Y_1, Y_3/Y_1, \ldots, Y_n/Y_1)$ satisfy precisely the conditions satisfied by $(Y_1, \ldots, Y_{n-1})$.**  Consequently

$$\eqalign{
f_n(t) &= E[(1-tY_1) E[(1-tY_2)\cdots(1-tY_n)\,|\, Y_1]] \\
       &= E\left[(1-tY_1) E\left[\left(1 - tY_1 \frac{Y_2}{Y_1}\right)\cdots \left(1 - tY_1 \frac{Y_n}{Y_1}\right)\,|\, Y_1\right]\right] \\
       &= E\left[(1-tY_1) f_{n-1}(tY_1)\right].
}$$

**This is the recursive relationship we were looking for.**

In the limit as $n\to \infty$ it must therefore be the case that for $Y$ uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$ independently of all the $Y_i$,

$$f(t) = E[(1 - tY)f(tY)]=\int_0^1 (1 - ty) f(ty) dy = \frac{1}{t}\int_0^t (1-x)f(x)dx.$$

That is, $f$ must be a fixed point of the functional $\mathcal{L}$ for which

$$\mathcal{L}[g](t) = \frac{1}{t}\int_0^t (1-x)g(x)dx.$$

---

### 3. Calculation of the Solution

Clear the fraction $1/t$ by multiplying both sides of the equation $f(t)=\mathcal{L}[f](t)$ by $t$.  Because the right hand side is an integral, we may differentiate it with respect to $t$, giving

$$f(t) + tf'(t) = (1-t)f(t).$$

Equivalently, upon subtracting $f(t)$ and dividing both sides by $t$,

$$f'(t) = -f(t)$$

for $0 \lt t \le 1$.  We may extend this by continuity to include $t=0$.  With the initial condition (3) $f(0)=1$, the *unique* solution is

$$f(t) = e^{-t}.$$

Consequently, by (4), the limiting expectation of $X_1X_2\cdots X_n$ is $f(1)=e^{-1} = 1/e$, QED.

---

Because *Mathematica* appears to be a popular tool for studying this problem, here is *Mathematica* code to compute and plot $f_n$ for small $n$.  The plot of $f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4$ displays rapid convergence to $e^{-t}$ (shown as the black graph).

```
a = 0 <= t <= 1;
l[g_] := Function[{t}, (1/t) Integrate[(1 - x) g[x], {x, 0, t}, Assumptions -> a]];
f = Evaluate@Through[NestList[l, 1 - #/2 &, 3][t]]
Plot[f, {t,0,1}]
```

[image: Figure]

Comment: (+1) Beautiful analysis.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that with us. There are some really brilliant people out there!

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

I think it's a safe bet that the answer is $1/e$.  I ran the integrals for the expected value from $n=2$ to $n=100$ using *Mathematica* and with $n=100$ I got

```
0.367879441171442321595523770161567628159853507344458757185018968311538556667710938369307469618599737077005261635286940285462842065735614
```

(to 100 decimal places).  The reciprocal of that value is

```
2.718281828459045235360287471351873636852026081893477137766637293458245150821149822195768231483133554
```

The difference with that reciprocal and $e$ is

```
-7.88860905221011806482437200330334265831479532397772375613947042032873*10^-31
```

I think that's too close, dare I say, to be a rational coincidence.

The *Mathematica* code follows:

```
Do[
 x = Table[ToExpression["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, n}];
 integrand = Expand[Simplify[(x[[n - 1]]/(1 - x[[n - 1]])) 
Integrate[x[[n]], {x[[n]], x[[n - 1]], 1}]]];
 Do[
   integrand = Expand[Simplify[x[[i - 1]] 
 Integrate[integrand, {x[[i]], x[[i - 1]], 1}]/(1 - x[[i - 
     1]])]],
   {i, n - 1, 2, -1}]
  Print[{n, N[Integrate[integrand, {x1, 0, 1}], 100]}],
 {n, 2, 100}]
```

**End of update**

This is more of an extended comment than an answer.

If we go a brute force route by determining the expected value for several values of $n$, maybe someone will recognize a pattern and then be able to take a limit.

For $n=5$, we have the expected value of the product being

$$\mu_n=\int _0^1\int _{x_1}^1\int _{x_2}^1\int _{x_3}^1\int _{x_4}^1\frac{x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5}{(1-x_1) (1-x_2) (1-x_3) (1-x_4)}dx_5 dx_4 dx_3 dx_2 dx_1$$

which is 96547/259200 or approximately 0.3724807098765432.

If we drop the integral from 0 to 1, we have a polynomial in $x_1$ with the following results for $n=1$ to $n=6$ (and I've dropped the subscript to make things a bit easier to read):

$x$

$(x + x^2)/2$

$(5x + 5x^2 + 2x^3)/12$

$(28x + 28x^2 + 13x^3 + 3x^4)/72$

$(1631x + 1631x^2 + 791x^3 + 231x^4 + 36x^5)/4320$

$(96547x + 96547x^2 + 47617x^3 + 14997x^4 + 3132x^5 + 360x^6)/259200$

If someone recognizes the form of the integer coefficients, then maybe a limit as  $n\rightarrow\infty$ can be determined (after performing the integration from 0 to 1 that was removed to show the underlying polynomial).

Comment: $1/e$ is beautifully elegant! :)

Answer (score 4):

Nice question. Just as a quick comment, I would note that:

- $X_n$ will converge to 1 rapidly, so for Monte Carlo checking, setting $n = 1000$ will more than do the trick.
- If $Z_n = X_1 X_2 \dots X_n$, then by Monte Carlo simulation, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $E[Z_n] \approx 0.367$.
- The following diagram compares the simulated Monte Carlo pdf of $Z_n$ to a Power Function distribution [ i.e. a Beta(a,1) pdf) ]

$$f(z) = a z^{a-1}$$

... here with parameter $a=0.57$:

[image]

<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/PowerFunctionfit.png))</sub>

where:

- the blue curve denotes the Monte Carlo 'empirical' pdf of $Z_n$
- the red dashed curve is a PowerFunction pdf.

The fit appears pretty good.

**Code**

Here are 1 million pseudorandom drawings of the product $Z_n$ (say with $n = 1000$), here using *Mathematica*:

```
    data = Table[Times @@ NestList[RandomReal[{#, 1}] &, 
            RandomReal[], 1000], {10^6}];
```

The sample mean is:

```
     Mean[data]
> 0.367657
```

Comment: can you share your entire code?  My solution differs from yours.

Comment: The first bullet point, which is crucial, does not appear to be sufficiently well justified.  Why can you dismiss the effect of, say, the next $10^{100}$ values of $x_n$?  Despite "rapid" convergence, their cumulative effect could considerably decrease the expectation.

Comment: Good use of simulation here. I have similar questions as @whuber. How can we be sure the value converges to 0.367 but not something lower, which is potentially possible if $n$ is larger?

Comment: In reply to the above 2 comments: (a) The series $X_i$ converges very rapidly to 1. Even starting with an initial value of $X_1 = 0.1$, within about 60 iterations, $X_{60}$ will be numerically indistinguishable from numerical 1.0 to a computer.  So, simulating $X_n$ with $n = 1000$ is overkill. (b) As part of the Monte Carlo test, I also checked the same simulation (with 1 million runs) but using $n = 5000$ rather than 1000, and the results were indistinguishable.  Thus, it seem unlikely that larger values of $n$ will make any discernible difference:  above $n=100$, $X_n$ *is* effectively 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Purely intuitively, and based on Rusty's other answer, I think the answer should be something like this:

```r
    n = 1:1000
    x = (1 + (n^2 - 1)/(n^2)) / 2
    prod(x)
```

Which gives us `0.3583668`. For each $X$, you are splitting the $(a,1)$ range in half, where $a$ starts out at $0$. So it's a product of $1/2, (1 + 3/4)/2, (1 + 8/9)/2$, etc.

This is just intuition.

---

The problem with Rusty's answer is that U[1] is identical in every single simulation. The simulations are not independent. A fix for this is easy. Move the line with `U[1] = runif(1, 0, 1)` to inside the first loop. The result is:

```r
    set.seed(3)    #Just for reproducibility of my solution
    
    n = 1000    #Number of random variables
    S = 1000    #Number of Monte Carlo samples
    
    Z = rep(NA,S)
    U = rep(NA,n)
    
    for(j in 1:S){
        U[1] = runif(1,0,1)
        for(i in 2:n){
            U[i] = runif(1,U[i-1],1)
        }
        Z[j] = prod(U)
    }
    
    mean(Z)
```

This gives `0.3545284`.

Comment: Very simple fix! I guess it is true, there is always a bug in the code! I'll take down my answer.

Comment: Yea, that was exactly what I was expecting to happen given that you plug in the expected values as the lower bounds.

Comment: I run your code with $S = 10000$ and got $0.3631297$ as the answer. Isn't that a little weird since if it does converge to a value wouldn't more runs get us closer to that value?